# installing older version sklearn using pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, pip

I am experimenting with some code that still uses the old sklearn module from sklearn.cross_validation import KFold. Instead I should use sklearn.model_selection, however this causes other errors inside the code.
I know version 0.17 of sklearn still has the depricated cross_validation. However I cannot install this using pip as it doesnt find that version.

I am using a virtuel envirement with python 3.3, how could I still use the older library?

Comment: `pip install scikit-learn==0.17` doesn't work?

Comment: [`scikit-learn` 0.17.1](https://pypi.org/project/scikit-learn/0.17.1/#files) requires Python 2.7, 3.3, 3.4 or 3.5. For a higher version you need to compile `scikit-learn` from [sources](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/releases/tag/0.17.1).

Comment: I reinstalled my virtuenenv with python 3.5.2 and installed numpy==1.16.0, when I install scipy==0.9 I keep on getting ValueError: 'build\\py3k\\scipy' is not a directory, when I just install scipy it works however then pip install scikit-learn==0.17 fails installing.